# Multiple references in Latex with page numbers

Tags: citing, natbib

I am writing a paper where I want to cite several references. This works fine with:

```
\citep{Ref1,Ref2,Ref3}
```

Producing a fine output.

But I cannot figure out how I add page numbers to this.

If I have one reference I will just do

```
\citep[3-4]{Ref1}
```

But how do I combine several references and only one of them needs to refer to a specific page(s)?

This does not work

```
\citep[3-4]{Ref1,Ref2,Ref3}
\citep{Ref1[3-4],Ref2,Ref3}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `natbib` package provides the "alternate" citation commands `\citealt` and `\citealp`, which act just like `\citet` and `\citep`, respectively, except that they don't generate parentheses.

I suggest you replace the single `\citep` directive with two `\citealp` directives; the first for the first entry (the one for which you want to provide a page range in the citation call-out), and the second for the 2nd and 3rd entries.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{j,author="Mandy Jones",title="Thoughts",year=3001}
@misc{m,author="Mary Miller",title="Thoughts",year=3002}
@misc{s,author="Molly Smith",title="Thoughts",year=3003}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
\setlength\parindent{0pt} % just for this example

\bibliographystyle{plainnat} % or some other suitable bib style

\begin{document}
\citep{j,m,s}

(\citealp[pp.\ 3--4]{j}; \citealp{m,s})
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks!!!